# Highchart js zoom remove labels of series from legend

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, zooming

I have a highstock from highchart.js that contains a lot of series. 
The series are time based (value per day). The chart has zoom enabled.
I'm trying to hide the label in the legend box of a series when I zoom in and this series is not present in the current zoom date window. Any idea how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `afterSetExtremes` event handler, where you will just remove series from your chart. When resetting zoom you will add all missing series.

Comment: I didn't succeed in doing it the way you described it but since it was a solid answer I accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have another solution? Share with us :)

Comment: Nope. I filtered the data before they are processed by highchart.